# how to click on radio button which is under a expanding tree node in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, ui-automation

->ABC

. 1

. 2

Here I have select "ABC" first which expands and shows two radio buttons. I have to find this element on a UI page and click on the 2nd radio button.

Comment: It is more useful if you show some code that you already have.

Answer (score 0):

as for me, to make it simple, I would like to add css class to those radios, so that I can use `find_element(css: '.a').click`. This is my lazy and yet effective approach.

Answer (score 0):

If both radio buttons belong to same group then they will have same names
You can extract both of them and click on second one

```
driver.findElements(By.name("common_name_of_radio_button").click();
```